# Disable button for a time period

Tags: javascript, html

After a user presses the send button, I want the send button to be disabled for 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds have elapsed, the button should be enabled again.

The `setTimeout(resetMaterialTextfield(messageInputElement), 10000);` function doesn't seem to work below.

```
function onMessageFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Check that the user entered a message that is a number between 1 and 100 and is signed in.
  if (messageInputElement.value && checkSignedInWithMessage()) {
    if (isNaN(messageInputElement.value)){
      window.alert(" Please enter a number between 1 - 100 (inclusive) ");
    }
    else {
      if (messageInputElement.value <= 0 || messageInputElement.value > 100){
        window.alert(" Please enter a number between 1 - 100 (inclusive) ");
      }
      else {
        saveMessage(messageInputElement.value).then(function () {
          // Clear message text field and re-enable the SEND button.
          setTimeout(resetMaterialTextfield(messageInputElement), 1000);
          toggleButton();
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the other function:

```
function toggleButton() {
  if (messageInputElement.value) {
    submitButtonElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    submitButtonElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
  }
}
```

Grateful for any help please.

Thank you!

Comment: setTimeout(resetMaterialTextfield(messageInputElement), 1000); calls resetMaterialTextfield immediately

Comment: Otherwise you need to show what resetMaterialTextfield does

Answer (score -1):

Try `setTimeout(resetMaterialTextfield.bind(null, messageInputElement), 1000);`

Comment: Thank you. 

I think it is the toggleButton that I need to time out for 10 seconds. I tried setTimeout(toggleButton(null), 10000); and that doesn't work.